Extraer la info de un archivo Json para ser usada muchas veces
Cómo puedo extraer la info de un archivo Json para ser usada muchas veces sin volver a escribir with open(...)...
import json
import time

# Declaramos una variable para el archivo Json. 
file_name = "biblioteca.json"

# Creamos la clase libro. 
class Libro:
    # Identifica las características de un libro. 
    def __init__(self, titulo, autor, inventario = True):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.autor = autor
        self.inventario = inventario
        
# Creamos la clase usuario. 
class usuario:
    # Nos define las características del usuario relacionadas a un libro/biblioteca. 
    def __init__(self, nombre, id, libros-prestados):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.id = id
        self.libros_prestados = libros_prestados
    
# Creamos la clase biblioteca. 
class Biblioteca:  
    def inicios(self):
        print('Iniciando programa. ')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Seleccione una de las siguientes opciones. ')
        print('1. Agregar libro a la biblioteca. ')
        print('2. Prestar libro a un usuario. ')
        print('3. Devolver libro a la biblioteca. ')
        print('4. Ver inventario de la biblioteca. ')
        accion = input()
        print()

        if accion == "1":
            Biblioteca.agregar_libro(self, libro)

    def agregar_libro(self, libro):        
        with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
            database = json.load(file)
            data_interna = database
            print(database)
            database[libro.titulo] = {
                "autor": libro.autor, 
                "inventario": libro.inventario, 
            }
            file.seek(0)
            json.dump(database, file, indent=4)
            file.truncate()
            print(database)

    def prestar_libro(self):
        with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
            database = json.load(file)
            if libro.titulo in database:
                if database[libro.titulo]["inventario"] < libro.inventario:
                    print('No hay suficientes libros en el inventario. ')
                
                else:
                    database[libro.titulo]["inventario"] -= libro.inventario
                    print('Préstamo registrado con éxito. Inventario actualizado con éxito. ')
                    print(f 'Libro: {libro.titulo} - {database[libro.titulo]}')

            else:
                print('El libro no se encuentra en inventario. ') 

titulo = input('Introduzca el titulo del libro ')
autor = input('Introduzca el autor del libro. ')
inventarios = input('Introduzca la cantidad de libro o presione N si el dato no es necesario. ')
inventario = inventarios if inventarios else ''

libro = Libro(titulo, autor, inventario)
biblioteca = Biblioteca(`introducir el código aquí`)
biblioteca.inicios()


Eso es una pregunta o una auto-respuesta? with permite que los archivos se cierren automáticamente, si no quieres usarlo puedes abrir el archivo en el constructor u otro método y mantener una referencia: self.file = open(...).

En realidad fue una pregunta. Soy un autodidacta y han conceptos que aun me faltan por aprender. Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho. Gracias.

Ahora sí se ve como una pregunta. El formato es importante
